# How to get Soft Input Keyboard height in multi-window supported devices?

Tags: android, keyboard

There are many examples present for getting keyboard height for the devices under Android N. And they worked very well. But in multi-window supported devices keyboard is not attached with the app window. It seems like static both for single window and multiple windows. So how I can get the keyboard height for multi-window supported devices?

Comment: Hey @MMBarno,
Did you find the solution? I'm also having the same problem